# How to clear firebase cache in 2024 Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a flutter app that fetches data from firebase and stores it in cache as so:

```
var snapshot = await ref.get(const GetOptions(source: Source.cache));
if (snapshot.docs.toString() == '[]') {
      var snapshot = await ref.get(const GetOptions(source: Source.server));
}
```

The problem now is that when I add or change something in firebase, it will never get updated even if I shut the app off and launch it again.

I have searched and only found solutions / partial solutions from 5 years ago and those didnt work.

I have tried: await `DefaultCacheManager().emptyCache();` and nothing happens

Additionally I have tried   `await FirebaseFirestore.instance.clearPersistence();` but I get an error and cannot seem to fix it.

I want that when I press on a button, the whole firebase cache disappears and it fetches the database once again. How can I achieve this? Thank you

clearPersistence error:

```
[VERBOSE-2:dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: [cloud_firestore/failed-precondition] Operation was rejected because the system is not in a state required for the operation's execution. If performing a query, ensure it has been indexed via the Firebase console.
#0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:652:7)
#1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:310:18)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      MethodChannelFirebaseFirestore.clearPersistence (package:cloud_firestore_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_firestore.dart:139:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
```

Comment: What error do you get using the clearPersistence method?

Comment: This check looks flaky: `snapshot.docs.toString() == '[]'`. Did you consider `snapshot.size == 0`?

Comment: I added the error in the post.

Comment: I will change it, thank you. It was for testing purposes